# Create unit test for unlikely scenario and is it worth the trouble?

Tags: java, unit-testing

For below method, is there a way to create unit test to cause `DatatypeConfigurationException`, so I can test that it threw `ConversionException`?

Here is my code:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getXMLGregorianCalendar(final LocalDate localDate) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = null;
    if (localDate != null) {
        final String dateString = localDate.format(yyyMMddFormat);
        try {
            xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateString);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ConversionException("Unable to format LocalDate.", e);
        }
    }

    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

Comment: I've answered with a way to test that code, whether or not it is worth it is a matter of opinion and highly dependent on your particular case.

Comment: It is best not to use singletons but use injectable instances for factories. If you followed that your test would be trivial, you would inject a mock that throws and exception when called, and you could test it in 3 lines of code. And yes, it is worth doing it as your downstream code may actually have logic around handling `ConversionException` and a diffent one for a generic case of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: As shown, for your question "is it worth the trouble?" the answer is no. The catch handling is trivial. However, you should test that the code that calls getXMLGregorianCalendar handles the exception correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the checked exception is thrown by `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance()`.
It is a static method. So you cannot mock it straightly.

1) As alternative you could try to find the scenario that could provoke the exception to be risen.
Let's go. The exception is throw here :

```
private static <T> T findServiceProvider(final Class<T> type)
        throws DatatypeConfigurationException{
    try {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<T>() {
            public T run() {
                final ServiceLoader<T> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(type);
                final Iterator<T> iterator = serviceLoader.iterator();
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    return iterator.next();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(ServiceConfigurationError e) {
        final DatatypeConfigurationException error =
                new DatatypeConfigurationException(
                    "Provider for " + type + " cannot be found", e);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

So `DatatypeConfigurationException` is thrown when `ServiceConfigurationError` is thrown and caught. But  `ServiceConfigurationError` is an error and not an exception.
Trying to simulate an error becomes very hacky.

2) Other alternative to test it : wrapping  `DatatypeFactory.newInstance()` in an instance of your own class.
In this way you can mock it without difficulty :

```
public class DataTypeFactoryWrapper { 
   public DatatypeFactory newInstance(){
      return DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
   }
}
```

Now change your code in this way  :

```
private DataTypeFactoryWrapper dataTypeFactoryWrapper;

//...
xmlGregorianCalendar = dataTypeFactoryWrapper.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateString);
```

Now you can mock `dataTypeFactoryWrapper` in your test class.

3) Last alternative : don't test it. Consider it as it is, that is an `Error` wrapper and `Error` are hard/tricky to test.
Whatever the javadoc explains that :

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions

Answer (score 2):

You can override the implementation that the factory will create by setting a system property with a classname to instantiate. Then that class can throw an exception in that method.

For example like this

```
public class FailingDatatypeFactory implements DatatypeFactory {
   public XMLGregorianCalendar newXMLGregorianCalendar() { throw new DatatypeConfigurationException() }
}
```

and then set it up like so

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory", FailingDatatypeFactory.class.getName());
```

Now after you run your test case you should clear the property so no other tests try to instantiate that implementation.

Comment: In this example how would you check in a test that newXMLGregorianCalendar method was called for the correct dateString?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The factory has to implement other methods.  Note also that it will not compile for another reason :  you throw a checked exception that is not declared in the interface. It is not valid. At last you stub an exception that is never thrown by this method itself. It is thrown by `DatatypeFactory.newInstance()`

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do this for my unit tests. All you need to do is set the Sys prop javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory to something invalid. It will throw the exception when it tries to find the class that doesn't exist. Just be sure to clear the prop after your test.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Mock static method (DatatypeFactory.newInstance()) using PowerMock for example and set it up to throw DatatypeConfigurationException. Then in unit test check that this exception is wrapped by ConversionException.
2. Since I'm not a big fan of mocking static methods - I would create new component - say XmlGregorianCalendarProvider (which will use DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateString) internally) and mock it instead using standard mocking mechanism (e.g. JUnit). 
   Still then in unit test check that this exception is wrapped by ConversionException.

Comment: This is controlled, and looks like new code. My rule of thumb is: never use Powermock on new code as it smells of bad code. Getting rid of static singleton factory there in favor of an injectable interface instance would enable testing even without mocking (simply by faking the interface).

Comment: Oleg - thats why I'm proposing option 2. Mocking is really isn't different from custom interface implementation and is more readable.

Comment: Right, I wish the order was different, that is the better option first. There would be no questions then :)